# How do I run a preview of a query in the new BigQuery Cloud Console GUI?

Tags: google-bigquery

The old GUI, at bigquery.cloud.google.com, allowed running  a Preview at much lower cost, like this:

[image: old GUI]

The new GUI, at console.cloud.google.com/bigquery, is said [by the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-costs#preview-data) to have such a feature, but no such option is visible, as in this screenshot:

[image: new GUI]

How do I do this in the new GUI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The preview option works for exploring data in tables, not for queries. It is available in both UIs on the Table Details page. Select a table first and you will see it.

Comment: Thank you. How  does "preview" differ from an ordinary query? After all, it still has to query the table.

Comment: Not really sure about the internals, I did notice that the way of doing this using command line does not create a query job so that might be a clue that it does not run an usual select. `Because the bq head command does not create a query job, bq head commands do not appear in your query history, and you are not charged for them.`

Comment: @Lak - I think your statement is not correct - preview uses tabledata.list and allows navigate through whole tables' data - in UI user can navigate using respective first|prev|next|last controls - can you please clarify

Comment: Mikhail, you are right. I was just pointing out why Preview can be free while a SELECT query needs to be charged.  My comment was misleading, though. removed it.